# Sqlite: sorting with special characters danish æ ø å

Tags: iphone, sqlite, sorting

I´ve got a sqlite database in my Iphone App. I have a table with names that needs sorting when using sectionIndexTitlesForTableView in the tableView.

The sql statement is "`SELECT * FROM buildings ORDER BY name ASC`". That gives a sorted result, but somehow the sorting fails on special characters - the danish æ ø å. 
Like:

- Århus Universitet
- Århus Å
- Øer Maritime Ferieby

Å should come after Ø.

I´ve tried reading up on COLLATE but feel pretty clueless on what to do here. Please note that the sqlite seems to work fine - using UTF8 encoding, everythings looks fine in the app. Except the alphabet ordering.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Since I only needed correct sorting for the array used in  sectionForSectionIndexTitle - table view datasource I bypassed the sorting issue in sqlite by doing:

`NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"da_DK"];
sections = [sections sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSDictionary *first, NSDictionary *second) {
        NSString *str1 = [first objectForKey:@"section"];
        NSString *str2 = [second objectForKey:@"section"];`

```
    return [str1 compare:str2
                  options:0
                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [str1 length])
                   locale:locale];
```

}];


I think its ok to do this since the number of entries in the section array will not exceed the number of characters in the alphabet.